# Dynamic Data View based on the type of user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have dynamic data website, there are 3 Roles: Admin, Data Entry and User. I want it that User can only view, Data Entry can Add/View and Admin can Add/Edit/View.

The user will have his/her authentication in Session["user"] and his authority is stored in db.

I am not getting a way , I don't want to try C# bits it too complex neither I want to use forms authentication.

I want a simple solution.

I am using C# and ASP.Net VS 2010

Comment: so what is stored in the session? and what does the table in the database look like?

Comment: @Sheena just if i am making simple login website i will store user id in session, session will contain authentic user id.When user will go to Dynamic Data Menu , can see all the tables. Upon clicking if authority is only to view than no edit / delete / insert options should be visible.